# Is there a third-party service for receiving email and accessing via an API?

Tags: web-services, email

I'd like to build a feature into our web app that involves receiving and processing the contents of an email.

But instead of going through the hassle of getting email setup on our server, it'd be *really* nice if there were a third-party service where I could forward emails and they could then process them and make the contents of the email available via an API.

Flow would go like this:

1. Customer sends email to new@example.com
2. new@example.com forwards to unique_id@some-email-processor.com
3. some-email-processor.com accepts the email and then stores it.
4. I then make an API every X amount of time to retrieve the new emails

Are there any services like that out there?

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/ perhaps?

Comment: What prevents you from using API for SMTP, POP3, or IMAP that most mail-services provide?

Comment: I notice that three of us (J.F. Sebastian, Carl Smotricz and myself) have now given more or less the same answer. Shpigford, could you clarify what you are looking for that differs from how we three would all apparently approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign yourself or your company up for a mail account with GMail (that's Google) or any other mail provider that gives you SMTP access. Then your application can use that service as its mailbox to the world. It doesn't get much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The application you are proposing does pretty much what any email client that leaves the content on the server does. Offhand, all you need is a server that allows access by your client using such standard protocols as SMTP.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid "needing" anything...except this service. Looking for something quick and easy that really involves very little setup other than connecting to the third-party web service.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest mailgun from rackspace -> http://www.mailgun.com/

Comment: Asking for or recommending tools/applications for performing a particular task is out of this forum's scope.

Comment: Original posters asked for an API-controllable third-party mail service, and this answer actually answers his (off-topic) question. It doesn't deserve being down-voted.